# Java substring.equals versus ==

Tags: java, awk, iteration, substring

Using the standard loop, I compared a substring to a string value like this:

```
if (str.substring(i, i+3) == "dog" ) dogcount++;
```

and it broke the iteration. After the first increment, no further instances of "dog" would be detected.

So I used substring.equals, and that worked:

```
if (str.substring(i, i+3).equals("dog")) dogcount++;
```

My question is, why? Just seeking better understand, thx.

Comment: this has been asked/answered so many times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: disagree with downvoters. @Cshift3iLike this is such a basic question that it's not surprising that one would have hard time finding the answer.

Comment: It seems some of the members are having fun with the people who are answering. Why all the unnecessary downvotes?! It's stupid!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `equals()` instead of `==` to compare two strings.

`s1 == s2` returns true if both strings **point to the same object in memory**. This is a common beginners mistake and is usually not what you want.

`s1.equals(s2)` returns true if both strings are **physically equal** (i.e. they contain the same characters).

Comment: Thx much. But why does using == break the iteration? Even if the count variable isn't incremented, I'd expect the iteration to continue.

Comment: You never mentioned what the "loop" was in your question, so I can't be sure. The loop could be `while(true) { }` for all I know.

Comment: It's from http://codingbat.com/prob/p111624:

    public boolean catDog(String str) {
      int dogcount = 0;
      int catcount = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<str.length()-2; i++) {
        if (str.substring(i, i+3).equals("dog")) dogcount++;
        if (str.substring(i, i+3).equals("cat")) catcount++;
      }
      return (dogcount == catcount);
    }

But I believe I misinterpreted my results. Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

`==` compares references. You want to compare values using `equals()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`==` compares references(storage location of strings) of strings

**and**

`.equals()` compares value of strings

Comment: @downvoter care to say why downvoted ? –is it wrong kind of answer?

Comment: Some idiots are down-voting all of the answers. Maybe they feel you are encouraging poor questions like this one by giving an answer?

Comment: Exactly! This should be reported I feel.

Answer (score 4):

For `String` comparison, always use `equals()` method. Because comparing on `==` compares the references.

Here's the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for further knowledge.

You might also want to read [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/409507/java/java/Difference-between-equals) for understanding difference between `==` and `equals()` method in a better way along with code examples.

Answer (score 3):

"String" is an object in Java, so "==" compares the references, as stated.
However, code like

```
String str1 = "dog";
String str2 = "dog";
if(str1==str2)
    System.out.println("Equal!");
```

will actually print out "Equal!", which might get you confused. The reason is that JVM optimizes your code a little bit when you assign literals directly to `String` objects, so that str1 and str2 actually reference the **same** object, which is stored in the internal pool inside JVM. On the other hand, code

```
String str1 = new String("dog");
String str2 = new String("dog");
if(str1==str2)
    System.out.println("Equal!");
```

will print out nothing, because you explicitly stated that you want two new objects.
If you want to avoid complications and unexpected errors, simply never use "==" with strings.